# Difference between Sapi 5.4 and Microsoft Speech Platform SDK 11

Tags: sapi, winapi

Okey, I've ask the question in Windows Desktop Development Forums and I still got no answer. So I'll try here.

What is the difference between Microsoft Sapi 5.4 and Microsoft Speech Platform SDK 11? Please specify the pros and cons if you know.

Comment: The general rule here is one question per post. It shouldn't be a problem here, because #1 is the only one that should be asked. #2 is asking for opinion or speculation ("Which is better"), and can be answered by your own research when looking at MSDN (which OSs are supported), as can #3. Also, #1 is answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5204562/62576), which is in the `Related` list to the right of your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between System.Speech.Recognition and Microsoft.Speech.Recognition?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977338/what-is-the-difference-between-system-speech-recognition-and-microsoft-speech-re)

Comment: See the table [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj127858.aspx) in the "Speech Platform features compared with SAPI" section.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, in programmatical sense there is no difference in the interface when connecting to it using COM interop. It's just a different class name.

SAPI uses: "SAPI:SPVoice"

MSSP uses: "speech.SPVoice"

for TTS access and everything else is the same.

As for other pros and cons better  take a look at table mentioned in  the comment above.